# Setting ASP.Net cache PrivateBytesLimit in C# service

Tags: .net, caching

I have a C# service which is not an ASP.NET application, but uses a singleton instance of of class HttpRuntime to cache items in its cache member. The singleton is created like this:

```
static private System.Web.HttpRuntime _httpRuntime = new HttpRuntime();
```

I want to set its maximum memory usage so I have the following in the app's config file service.exe.config:

```
<configuration>
 <caching>
    <cache privateBytesLimit= "50000000"   privateBytesPollTime = "00:01:00"/>
 </caching>
</configuration>
```

This doesn't seem to have any effect. Instead of setting it to 50MB, when I look in HttpRuntime.Cache.EffectivePrivateBytesLimit it is 720 MB.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: HttpRuntime.Cache is static, so what do you gain by creating a new HttpRuntime instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the correct cache element. According to the documentation the [EffectivePrivateBytesLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.effectiveprivatebyteslimit.aspx) property can be set with the privateBytesLimit attribute of the [cache Element for caching (ASP.NET Settings Schema) element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228248%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in the application's configuration file;

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <caching>
      <cache privateBytesLimit="10000000" privateBytesPollTime="00:01:00" />
    </caching>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```